# Nix: how to change stdenv in nixpkgs.mkShell

Tags: nix

I'd like to override the stdenv for `mkShell` to use gcc10Stdenv. I've looked at https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Using_Clang_instead_of_GCC, which provides instructions for overriding stdenv, but it doesn't describe how to do it for `mkShell` when just making a shell without reference to any specific package (only for "Using Nix CLI on existing packages").

My question is whether it's possible to override stdenv for mkShell without an existing package? And if so, how?

Comment: Not sure if helpful but: 

It seems mkShell is defined here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix

Which according to the discussion here https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/58624, makes me think you possibly just implement your own 'mkShell' that originates from your gcc10Stdenv?

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```nix
pkgs.mkShell.override {stdenv = pkgs.gcc10Stdenv} {
  inputsFrom = ...;
  ...
}
```

This is the standard way to alter the inputs to packages (which are just functions) in nixpkgs. It should work in this case.

Alternately, you could just copy the [mkShell implementation](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix) into `./mkShell.nix` and import it, as Chris suggested.

```nix
let mkShell = import ./mkShell.nix;
in mkShell {
  lib = pkgs.lib; 
  stdenv = pkgs.gcc10Stdenv;
} { 
  inputsFrom = ...;
}
```

This is just a regular function, so  we're calling it with two parameters.